# Regex.Replace() with variable for pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have this code:

```
a += Regex.Replace(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), " \\(AB\\)|\\(BC\\)|\\(CD\\)", "").Replace(" ", "");
```

which turns "Hallo (AB) (C)" into "Hallo(C)" (works perfectly)

now i want to replace the pattern with a variable:

```
string patt=" \\(AB\\)|\\(BC\\)|\\(CD\\)";
a += Regex.Replace(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), @patt, "").Replace(" ", "");
```

and it doesn´t work anymore. 
I was looking for solutions but i didn´t found anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that you don't have a @ in the original statement, adding a @ in front of the string in the second will alter the meaning of the backslashes in that string. Have you tried without the @ altogether?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Note that the @ in the second code snippet is *not* creating a verbatim string since `patt` is a variable, not a string literal; so it won't alter the meaning of the backslashes in that string.

Comment: @j0h4nn3s What exactly does not work? The code you posted works fine and doesn't show any issue.

Comment: I'm saving the pattern in a xml-file and reading it with `string patt=reader.ReadElementContentAsString()` I thought that this is the same as `string patt="" \\(AB\\)|\\(BC\\)|\\(CD\\)"` but you are right, in this case it is working. But it isn't working after adding the xml-Reader

Comment: @j0h4nn3s have you checked what `reader.ReadElementContentAsString()` actually returns?

Comment: @Dominic I have checked it and it turned out that it was exactly the same, but comparing the two strings I found out, that the working RegEx-String was `\(AB\)|\(BC\)|\(CD\)`. Changing the string in the xml file and adding the `@` again was the solution.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `@` is in the wrong place, perhaps you mean the following:

```
string patt= @" \\(AB\\)|\\(BC\\)|\\(CD\\)";
a += Regex.Replace(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), patt, "").Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: No. By creating a verbatim string you change the meaning of the pattern. The backslash is escaped in the non-verbatim string to escape the `(`.

Comment: Just try to remove the `@` from the variable name.

Comment: @Selman22 It doesn't matter if it's a verbatim identifier or not.